# How to create a React Component that will render an image if provided?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I was thinking about creating a simple blog type website to practice my beginner React skills, where each post consists of 3 elements: a title, details and optionally a picture/set of pictures. I was thinking of creating a reusable React component for each blog post and I can pass in the data for the title, details and picture/s. Since the posts themselves can optionally have pictures or not how would someone go about the part of the component to conditionally render something that may or may not be passed in? Is there a special html tag to use or is there code in jsx/typescript to detect whether or not an image is passed in as an argument for a component? I have not written any code yet I am simply brainstorming an approach before starting so I have a general direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In typescript we can add ? at the end of a variable type declaration to declare that they are optional. I implemented my component so that it takes in an array of strings which is an array of the paths to the images. I conditionally rendered images using the ternary operator and if the image path exists then i can do  inside of array.map((path)...) if it is missing then return null. This works the way I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If the image is fetched from the backend as a URL, you can try this.

```
imageUrl && <ImageComponent url=imageUrl />
```

Here only if imageUrl exists, does the component gets rendered.

There are also a lot of options to conditionally render components in React.